# keyboard wedge device into android usb

Tags: android, usb

I have a measurement device which sends data as keyboard wedge when connected to a PC. I would like to be able to use it to input data into an Android phone or tablet through the USB port.
Anyone have an an idea if Android device USB port can be used in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Only some Android devices support USB host mode, but those that do would typically recognize a keyboard as a keyboard and use it as such.  An adapter cable is typically required.

One problem this might present is that if your app goes to the background, you would probably lose the keyboard input as it would instead go to whatever is in the foreground. The Android security model, if still intact, would prevent snooping on keyboard input when not in the foreground.

(They often support mice too - kind of funny to see a mouse cursor appear on your phone)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your particular model of Android device, you may be able to use [this adapter](http://goo.gl/J11Ax), or one like it, to connect a keyboard via Android's support for [USB On-The-Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go)